# How to filter response as required(collections)?

Tags: apex

for the below code i got the response below step 1 shows i'm after 
  that little confuse at filter the response like below step 2:

```
           Map<String,String> test = new Map<String,String>();
           Map<String,String> samp= new Map<String,String>();
            Set<String> listofrecords= new Set<String>();


      for(String first : samp.keySet()){                     
                  String firstValue = samp.get(first);                    
                for(String second : test.keySet()){                      
                    String secondValue = test.get(second);                      
                       if(firstValue.equals(second)){ 

                              listofrecords.add(secondValue);
                               System.debug('listofrecords:::---------'+listofrecords);

                  }
                }
              }
```

step 1 :I got the response like below

```
             test
             test,test@gmail.com
             test,test@gmail.com,9999999999
```

step 2 :Insted of that how to get the response like below

```
             test
             test@gmail.com
             99999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the list in a loop, and using the default join method, so it's expected you'd see that type of output. Instead, show it outside of the loop:

```
for(String first : customsettingValues.keySet()){                     
  ...
}
System.debug('listofrecords:::---------\n'+String.join(new List<String>(listofrecords), '\n');
```